# Swift: Unable to refresh rootViewController with pushNotification's info when the application is running in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, push-notification

I am implementing a news App. Once I receive a notification with a breaking news id and message, i am supposed to open the app and refresh the rootViewController with the id received in the push notifications.

Things work fine when the application is not running in the background while an issue arises when the application is running in the background.

In the AppDelegate.swift i have set the didReceiveRemoteNotifications as follows

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        strNotificationId = (userInfo["id"] as? String)!
}
```

In my applicationWillEnterForeground i have called the rootViewController method activeController.request() that reloads the page with the id received as shown below

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")

        if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as?UINavigationController {
            navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
        }        
        let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        let activeController = navigationController!.visibleViewController as! FeedTableViewController

        activeController.request("http://example.net/rsssite.xml")
}
```

My rootViewController implements the request("http://example.net/rsssite.xml") method. The request method reads the notification id as shown below

```
delegate.notificationId = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
notificationId = delegate.strNotificationId as String
```

My issue is showing that whenever i click on my notification received in the IOS notifications list, and when the app happens to be running in the backend, the request("http://example.net/rsssite.xml") that is implemented in the rootViewController is neither being triggered in my rootViewController viewDidLoad nor in applicationWillEnterForeground

Below is a full the full code of my request(url) method in my rootViewController which might be useless for your feedback

```
//Method to request and parser the rss feeds
        func request(urlLink: String){


            forceError = false
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: Util.getMessage("loading"), preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

            loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
            loadingIndicator.startAnimating();


            alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
            self.view.addSubview(alert.view)
            self.view.bringSubviewToFront(loadingIndicator)

            let viewsDictionary = ["alert":alert.view]
            let loadingMetrics = ["xDimension":(self.view.bounds.size.width - alert.view.frame.width ) / 2, "yDimension": (self.view.bounds.size.height - alert.view.frame.height ) / 2]

            let horizontalLoadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-50-[alert]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics:loadingMetrics, views: viewsDictionary)
            let verticalLoadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-100-[alert]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: loadingMetrics, views: viewsDictionary)

            self.view.addConstraints(horizontalLoadingConstraint)
            self.view.addConstraints(verticalLoadingConstraint)
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


            let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            let notificationsData = delegate.notificationId
            for aButton in notificationsData {
                let key = aButton.0
                let value = aButton.1
                if(key == "id"){
                    notificationId = value as! String
                }
            }

            delegate.notificationId = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
            notificationId = delegate.strNotificationId as String
            //notificationId = "17579"
            if (notificationId != "" && self.directLoad==false) {
                //var notificationURLLink = defaults.stringForKey("notificationId")
                let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(9999) + 1) as NSNumber
                let notificationURLLink = "http://example.net/"+notificationId+"-rss.xml?_=" + diceRoll.stringValue
                let queue = NSOperationQueue()
                queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
                    let url = NSURL(string: notificationURLLink)
                    let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: url)
                    feedParser.delegate = self

                    feedParser.parse()
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {
                        let item = self.feedItems[0] as MWFeedItem
                        self.slectedItems = item
                        self.sideBar.showSidebar(false)
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailsViewControllerSegue", sender: self)
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                        self.notificationId = ""
                        self.directLoad = true
                    }
                }
            }else{
                let queue = NSOperationQueue()
                queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
                    let url = NSURL(string: urlLink)
                    let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: url)
                    feedParser.delegate = self
                    feedParser.parse()

                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            delegate.strNotificationId = ""
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try move your code in `applicationWillEnterForeground` to `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. The process should be done right after you receive the notification.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    strNotificationId = (userInfo["id"] as? String)!
    print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")

    if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as?UINavigationController {
        navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
    }        
    let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    let activeController = navigationController!.visibleViewController as! FeedTableViewController

    activeController.request("http://example.net/rsssite.xml")
}
```

Also please check which function execute first when you open the notification while the apps in background, `applicationWillEnterForeground` or `didReceiveRemoteNotification` ?